# function doesn't getting call from the class from the view file in python

Tags: python, django

When I call the class from views.py, it doesn't call the function of the class. I am calling the function `latest_question_list = Question.get_poll_question()` from views.py, but it doesn't print in my model function.

Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.


from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from .models import Choice, Question
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render



def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.get_poll_question()
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    try:
        question = Question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import connection

global cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

class Question():

    print(123)

    def get_poll_question():
        print(456)
        db_table = "polls_question"
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM '+db_table)
        return allquestions

class Choice():


    def __str__(self):
        db_table = "polls_choice"
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+ db_table+" WHERE question_id = '1' ")
        choice_text = cursor.fetchall();
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: In `get_poll_question()` you return `allquestions` but you never define this variable anywhere.

Comment: Why are you writing your own `Question` class and raw SQL queries? If you're learning Django, please [follow the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) and use Django models, e.g. `class Question(models.Model):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the method as `classmethod`. Also using that global cursor
IMO is a very bad idea.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

```py
class Question:

    @classmethod
    def get_poll_question(cls):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            db_table = "polls_question"
            cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {db_table}")
            return cursor.fetchall()
```

Probably another best way of doing would be creating a model. If you don't
control the table, you can create an [unamanged Django model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.managed)

Comment: My question is why i am not getting print : 456, why it doesn't call the function ?

Comment: i tried your code still it doesn't printing 456 in my cli console